# Populating ListView with data from mySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, gson

Im trying to populate my listView with data from my database. i have tbl_table with only tableID and tableCapacity. i tried running my phpcodes to postman, and in the printing in the log too, and it seems that there is no problem, so i figured that it must be because of the way i convert the Json encode. i keep on getting this error. thanks in advance.. im running my codes in android 4.1.2 API 16.

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter.toArrayList(JsonConverter.java:42)
    at markjon.nobleza.qaldi.Table.onResponse(Table.java:51)                                                               
    at markjon.nobleza.qaldi.Table.onResponse(Table.java:20)
```

Here is my Codes:

Table.class

```
public class Table extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.Listener<String> {

    final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    ListView tableLV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);

        String URL = "http://192.168.1.10/myDB/table.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, this, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error retrieving data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        tableLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tableList);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response);


        ArrayList<myTable> tableList = new JsonConverter<myTable>().toArrayList(response, myTable.class);

        BindDictionary<myTable> dict = new BindDictionary<>();
        dict.addStringField(R.id.tableNum, new StringExtractor<myTable>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(myTable item, int position) {
                return "" + item.tableID;
            }
        });

        dict.addStringField(R.id.tableCap, new StringExtractor<myTable>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(myTable item, int position) {
                return "" + item.tableCapacity;
            }
        });

        FunDapter<myTable> adapter = new FunDapter<>(getApplicationContext(), tableList, R.layout.table_layout, dict);

        tableLV.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

myTable.class

```
public class myTable {

    @SerializedName("tableID")
    public int tableID;
    @SerializedName("tableCapacity")
    public int tableCapacity;

}
```

The error point on these two lines:

```
public class Table extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.Listener<String>

ArrayList<myTable> tableList = new JsonConverter<myTable>().toArrayList(response, myTable.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `response` variable should be a proper json string, but it has not the right format. According to the error message and as it is expected to be a json array, this json string should start with array symbol, i.e. `[` and ends with `]`. 
I suggest that you use a break point on this line and evaluate the value of `response` variable. You can use [online json formatters/validators](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) to find out what is wrong in this json string. Then you should change the logic of the method that creates this json.